# How to make text on Image responsive with a specific position?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive website but I cant place my text on my image perfectly without it moving somewhere.
I'm a beginner just for your information.

```css
    .line-1{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 24em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    text-shadow: 3px 3px  #000000;}

    #text {
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    left: 27%;
    top: 25%;}
```

```html
  <div>
        <img id="image" src="service.png" alt="Service Angebot"
        height="60%" width="60%" />
        <a href="service.html"><p id="text" class="line-1 anim-typewriter">
          Unser Serviceangebot</p></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you inspect the <p> tag in your browser do you see position relative from the class or position absolute from the id? You are applying both to the same tag.

Comment: @JasonAller I dont really get what you mean sry

Comment: The `.line-1` rule is being applied to the same `<p>` that the `#text` rule is being applied to and they have conflicting settings for `position`.

Comment: @JasonAller do you mean that text-align: center; thing?

Comment: I removed the position thing its still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to make the image into the div background ? Use this property : background-image: url("service.png");

Comment: No I want my text to not move around when Im resizing my window

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div id=image><a href="service.html"><p id="text" class="line-1 anim-    typewriter">Unser Serviceangebot</p></a></div>
```

Css:

```
#image{
  background: url(service.png) no-repeat;
  padding: ;/* Resize it for your picture! *

}
#image a{
padding: 4px; 
}
```

Comment: But my Image is huge thats why I set it to 60% and I dont want to make my image I want my text to not move anywhere when Im resizing the window

Comment: I think that text is not going to move

Comment: your thing doesnt work at all my image is not even showing

Comment: and the text is still moving

Comment: Lol, I don't know what are you doing but works fine m8 just resize that for your image ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could help you but I get everything under the same div, and float them with:

```
#img
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 0;

    }
#txt
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using Bootstrap cards. That should fix the issue.

```
<div class="card card-inverse">
  <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No I want the text to be displayed on the image