# How to overlay text on top of a responsive image -- responsively?

Tags: html, css

I want my text to not move anywhere outside of the Image when I resize my window. But with this Code its wandering up and down when I'm resizing it.
My text is an animation but that shouldn't matter right?

```css
  .line-1{
    width: 24em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    text-shadow: 3px 3px  #000000;}

    /* Animation */
    .anim-typewriter{
       animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both,
                 blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
    }
    @keyframes typewriter{
      from{width: 0;}
      to{width: 11em;}
    }
    @keyframes blinkTextCursor{
      from{border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
      to{border-right-color: transparent;}
    }
    
    #image {
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    #text {
      z-index: 200;
      position: absolute;
      left: 27%;
      top: 25%;
    }
```

```html
    <center>
          <div>
            <img id="image" src="service.png" alt="ZJ-Automobile Service Angebot"
            height="60%" width="60%" />
            <a href="zjservice.html"><p id="text" class="line-1 anim-typewriter">
              Unser Serviceangebot</p></a>
          </div>
        </center>
```

Is the html maybe wrong? I really don't get what could be wrong here.
Also I'm a beginner so please keep that in mind.
I tried to ask my question differently.

[After resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FB8J.png)

See what I mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make text on Image responsive with a specific position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170016/how-to-make-text-on-image-responsive-with-a-specific-position)

Comment: @AndrewClody well I tried to ask my question differently so people could maybe help me more now since none of the help in the last post really adressed my problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put you need 2 areas with 1 position:relative; and 1 position:absolute;

Look at this example I made with a loading image to show you how it works.

It wants some code to link a jsfiddle.

```
  #thisbanner {
  max-width: 700px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/nbfg3gtd/

Not all demos work on Stack so I will try to add it here, if not please refer to Jsfiddle demo link above.

```css
  #thisbanner {
  max-width: 700px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: -12%;
  max-width: 610px;
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', Rockwell, Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 .125em .125em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: .6em 1em .6em 1.7em;
}

.interior-header img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #b22222;
  padding: 1px;
```

```html
<div id="thisbanner">
  <div class="interior-header img">
    <div class="headerimage">

      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3eqP.jpg" width="630" height="240" alt="Traffic Control" />

      <h1>Traffic Control</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it all worked out for you @KrisJ. Hope its a start of a good weekend. Cheers!

Comment: Oh you cant believe how happy I am right now :D Everything is working :)) Thank you very much!